Omni Channel flow not assigning cases to a queue when it is reply to an email on the case
I have enabled Email to Case in the organization. Whenever a new email is sent, a new case is created, and the email message is attached to that case. Additionally, when an email is sent as a reply, it gets attached to the correct case as well. Both these two scenarios are working as expected.
Now I have an Omni channel flow created to assign cases to correct queues depending on if it is a new email or a reply to an email.
The Omni channel flow is added over here on setup -


If it is a new email a new case gets created and Omni channel flow should route it to the Escalation Queue.
If it is a reply to an email on an existing case then the Omni channel flow should route it to the Follow up Queue.

Here what I am noticing is the new cases are correctly routed to the Escalation Queue by the Omni channel flow but when there is a reply to an email on an existing those cases are not routed to the Follow Up Queue by the Omni Channel Flow.
Does the Omni Channel flow trigger when there is a reply to an email on an existing case?
Here is my Omni Channel Flow -


Create a flow on Email Message object. Have a decision to check if the ParentId is null or not null. If the parent Id is null- you can create a new case else you can append it to an existing case.

Hello Jaya Harshit, This article mentions not to create any record triggered flows - https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=service.omnichannel_route_email_to_case.htm&type=5

Also I noticed ParentId is not null for a new email. When I checked the ParentId of the new email it takes me to the deleted case record.
